# Project Management Issues

Tags: project-management

I am leading a a software development team of 15 members. I am facing a list of problems are

```
Not getting enough time to do planning and tracking
Not able to make all team members busy
Not able to deliver products on the committed dates
```

What could be the possible ways to handle this? where can I get more information?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about project management, not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your job is to do the planning and tracking. This is your first responsibilty and you should not be doing other tasks ahead of this especially any coding. In fact, since you say you can't keep your people busy, you should not be doing any coding at all. You should start the day with tracking every day. If you don't know who is doing what and what they are stuck on and what they are ahead on, you don't know who is available to assign other tasks or who needs help. In other words, you are not managing if you don't do this task.

If you do the first task, the second should solve itself unless you have developers who are not capable of doing the tasks you have to assign. If so, get rid of the deadwood and hire better people.

If you do the first task, the third should either solve itself or give you the ammunition you need to go to the higher levels and request a deadline extension. These are easier to get when you have the detailed data to show that the work cannot fit into the time allotted.

Comment: I'd add to that "STOP CODING". If and only if you are all caught up on your planning and tracking task, then you may work on something that has no dependencies - at least anything that is due in less than a month (because you don't want to be holding up anyone else on the team).

Answer (score 1):

I think good planning is an essential part of the software development life cycle. Therefore, time *should* be spent on planning. Moreover, part if the planning is deciding who should do what and when (so that no one remains without anything to do). It also involves identification of potential risks for your project and combined with the task management, it should help you meet your deadline. All this of course depends on which process are you following.

Answer (score 0):

Software Estimation is probably a big part of it. I'd recommend Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art, by Steve McConnell. He runs [Construx](http://www.construx.com/), a company that helps out on that sort of stuff too. Using a tool that breaks down projects into smaller chunks like Microsoft Project or [Telerik Teampulse](http://www.telerik.com/agile-project-management-tools/teampulse.aspx) would probably be helpful.